# How do i prove f(0) = 0 (Calculus problem)

Tags: calculus, differential

I need some help to get started with this question.

$$f(x) + \ln(1+f(x)) = \frac{\sin x}{1+x}$$

Show $f(0) = 0$ and use that to find $f'(0)$.

Where do i start to show $f(0) = 0$? $f(x)$ inside $\ln(1+f(x))$ is confusing me a a lot.

Comment: The right side is $0$ for $x=0$, so you have $f(0)+\ln(1+f(0))=0$. Now, show that $r+\ln(1+r)=0$ has only the solution $r=0$ in the reals.

Answer (score 2):

For $x=0$, you get
$$f(0)+\ln(1+f(0))=0$$

so $f(0)$ is solution of the equation $y+\ln(1+y)=0$. Now, the function $g : y \mapsto y +\ln(1+y)$ is strictly increasing on its domain, so it is injective. Moreover, $g(0)=0$, so $0$ is the only solution to $g(0)=0$. So
$$f(0)=0$$